# access checkbox value in controller

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I'm trying to access the checkbox value from my angularjs controller.

My checkbox is as follows.

```
  <div class="checkbox"><label for="id_tokenization">
   <input ng-click="addProperties()" name="tokenization" type="checkbox" ng-model="vault.tokenization" value="store.preauth.approved_responses">
   Enable Tokenization</label></div>
  </div>
```

For my checkbox value i have given a string. I want to get that value to my controller. How can i do this?

Comment: Check this out [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D]

Comment: @CraZyDroiD Have you got a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply pass in the `modal` value on your `ng-click` attribute as parameter like

```
ng-click="addProperties(vault.tokenization)"
```

similarly in your markup

```
<input ng-click="addProperties(vault.tokenization)" name="tokenization" type="checkbox" ng-model="vault.tokenization" value="store.preauth.approved_responses">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
  <div class="checkbox"><label for="id_tokenization">
   <input ng-change="addProperties(store.preauth.approved_responses)  name="tokenization" type="checkbox" ng-model="vault.tokenization" ng-value="store.preauth.approved_responses">
   Enable Tokenization</label></div>
  </div>
```

And in your controller, you can check whether it was checked or not and if its been checked you can define your action over there :

```
$scope.addProperties = function(prod){
    var index = $scope.selected_products.indexOf(prod.name);
    if(index == -1 && prod.selected){
      $scope.selected_products.push(prod.name);
    } else if (!prod.selected && index != -1){
      $scope.selected_products.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the angular notation {{ }} which we use to refer the controller's data into model.
However make sure you have declared this into your controller.

```
 <input ng-click="addProperties()" name="tokenization" type="checkbox" ng-model={{vault.tokenization}} value="store.preauth.approved_responses">
```